# How to know the Variable/Property Name which was passed to a Method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

```
private static void AssertNotNullAndAreEqual<T, TK>(T expected, TK actual)
{
            Assert.IsNotNull(expected);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I can call it using:

```
AssertNotNullAndAreEqual(expected.FirstName, actual.FirstName);
```

Is there any simple way that I can know the "FirstName" text of the expected object from within this method?

I'd need it for logging purposes and giving proper error messages from within this method.

The C# caller information doesn't help here.

Comment: No, there isn't, you'll have to ensure you pass that information along with the value of the property.

Comment: The usual pattern for having something retrieve a value *and* know which value it was would be providing both the value storage and the value identifier, so the retrieving instance can fetch the value itself and know where it got it from.

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink that approach, because this might bite back at some point - but if you're really keen on getting some degree of automation, you could try this:

```
private static void AssertNotNullAndAreEqual<T, TK>(Expression<Func<T>> expected,
                                                    Expression<Func<TK>> actual)
{
   var memberExpression = expected.Body as MemberExpression;
   if (memberExpression != null)
   {
      var expectedMemberName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

      var expectedVal = expected.Compile()();
      var actualVal = actual.Compile()();

      Assert.IsNotNull(expectedVal);
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedVal, actualVal);

      //...
   }
}
```

Now your calls would have to look as follows:

```
AssertNotNullAndAreEqual(() => expected.FirstName, () => actual.FirstName);
```

Few more caveat

- a lot of stuff will not be checked until compile time (luckily type-safety is preserved). It's easy to write calls that will compile correctly, but fail at runtime.
- as this is written, it won't work with variables - but if you decide to go this way, it would be pretty easy to write.

Please use at your own discretion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ToString()` for another purpose (which I assume you are), you can define an interface and use it as a type constraint on `AssertNotNullAndAreEqual(...)`, or alternately check to see if the objects passed to `AssertNotNullAndAreEqual(...)` have the interface.

You define an interface, say `IDebugString`, which has a `ToDebugString()` method, then you call that to retrieve the info to log.